# Anybody knows if i could upload a leaflet or openlayers3 map to wordpress webpage?

Tags: uploads, directory, google-maps

I have an openlayers3 webmap edited by html,js and css. I want to upload my webmap into my wordpress webpage but i don't know how. I have filezilla to upload the files. Which directory is to upload the content in the ftp server(with filezilla)? It is possible or i only embed maps in wordpress with a plugins? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than uploading the static files, the "WordPress way" would be to:

1. Create a [child theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/)
2. Create a [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) - this is where you can include your HTML for the map. You will probably also want to include basic theme tags such as `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` so your header and footer are included and the page looks like the rest of your WordPress site. I would start by copying your current theme's `page.php` file and then adding the custom HTML in the middle, close to the Loop. Depending on your desire you may want to remove the Loop (which means any content you type into the Editor will not appear - only your hard-coded map will) or you might want to leave it in place so you can add text either above or below the map, depending on where you insert the map HTML.
3. [Enqueue the JS and CSS](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) - you can restrict it so they only appear on the map page, not the entire website.
4. Create a Page in WordPress - make sure to choose your Page Template, and once you publish it, WordPress will combine the HTML, JS, and CSS to display your map.

Comment: Hello Elaine, i have already create a child theme and a page template. Now, i'm trying to put the html into the php code. I don't know if it is correct because when i create a web map i have a css file, a js file, a geojson file and a kml file, and all works due to html (all files are called by the html file). There aren't any example about this. Do you know any example or something? i'm very grateful for your help

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on enqueuing the JS and CSS. They should be inserted through the child theme's `functions.php` file. The CSS will go into the `<head>`, but depending on how the JS is set up it may go in either the `<head>` or the bottom of the `<body>`, depends on the particular script - just try to match what's in your original HTML. Basically you'll want to sandwich content between the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` calls, so that any required HTML from the original map is inside the `<body>` tag.